# How to get the value of an element located in the parent element by class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to find the value of an element that is located in the parent, using the element's class name.

Below is my code that has a button in the same parent as the element I want to find, but when I click it I get "undefined".

```js
$(document).on('click', '.four', function(){                    
    var select = $(this).parents(".parent .two").html();
  console.log(select);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <p class="one"> one </p>
  <p class="two"> two </p>
  <p class="three"> three </p>
  <button  class="four"> button one </button>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <p class="one"> five </p>
  <p class="two"> six </p>
  <p class="three"> seven </p>
  <button  class="four"> button two </button>
</div>
```

Comment: where is liquid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).on('click', '.four', function(){                    
    var select = $(this).parents(".parent").find('.two').html();
    console.log(select);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <p class="one"> one </p>
  <p class="two"> two </p>
  <p class="three"> three </p>
  <button  class="four"> button one </button>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <p class="one"> five </p>
  <p class="two"> six </p>
  <p class="three"> seven </p>
  <button  class="four"> button two </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The class you are looking for (i.e. `.two`) is a child of the same parent so it is a *sibling*. You don't need to traverse up the `parents()` and back to get the sibling, you can do it like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.four', function(){   
    var select = $(this).siblings(".two").html();
}
```

Working Example:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.four', function(){                    
    var select = $(this).siblings(".two").html();
    console.log(select);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <p class="one"> one </p>
  <p class="two"> two </p>
  <p class="three"> three </p>
  <button  class="four"> button one </button>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <p class="one"> five </p>
  <p class="two"> six </p>
  <p class="three"> seven </p>
  <button  class="four"> button two </button>
</div>
```

If you really need to get traverse the parents for some reason, then you do it like this -first traverse the parents to get the one with the class you want, *then* get its `children()` with class `.two` :

```
$(this).parents(".parent").children(".two").html();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
let parent = document.getElementById('parent');
let childs = parent.childNodes;
console.log(childs[1].className)
```

```html
<div class="parent" id="parent">
  <p class="one"> five </p>
  <p class="two"> six </p>
  <p class="three"> seven </p>
  <button  class="four"> button two </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$(document).on('click', '.four', function(){
        console.log("clicked")
    var select = $(this).parent().find('.two').html();
  console.log(select);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

that ?

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button.four').forEach(btn=>{
  btn.onclick=_=>{
    console.log( btn.parentElement.querySelector('.three').textContent  )
  } })
```

```html
  <div class="parent">
    <p class="one"> one </p>
    <p class="two"> two </p>
    <p class="three"> three</p>
    <button  class="four"> button one </button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="parent ">
    <p class="one"> five </p>
    <p class="two"> six </p>
    <p class="three"> seven </p>
    <button  class="four"> button two </button>
  </div>
```